# How to get acces to json.net array?

Tags: c#, silverlight, parsing, windows-phone-7, json.net

```
{
  "response": [
    50961,
    {
      "mid": 148014,
      "date": 1309642994,
      "out": 0,
      "uid": 39050402,
      "read_state": 1,
      "title": " ... ",
      "body": "здоров"
    },
    {
      "mid": 148012,
      "date": 1309641130,
      "out": 0,
      "uid": 56015000,
      "read_state": 1,
      "title": "...",
      "body": ")"
    },
    {
      "mid": 148010,
      "date": 1309639892,
      "out": 0,
      "uid": 56015000,
      "read_state": 1,
      "title": " ... ",
      "body": "Привет)"
    },
```

How I parse it:

```
string json = e.Result;
var response = JObject.Parse(json);
Debug.WriteLine(response);
var messages_in = new iVk.App.MessagesInStructure[count_messages];
for (int i = 0; i < count_messages; i++)
{
    messages_in[i].readstate = Convert.ToBoolean(response["response"][i]["read_state"]);
    messages_in[i].text = response["response"][i]["body"].ToString();
    messages_in[i].otpravitel = response["response"][i]["uid"].ToString();
    messages_in[i].date_time = Convert.ToDateTime(response["response"][0][i]["date"]);
}
```

But nothing of it doesn't works..How I can get access to [response][date] and others?
I have error "Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue."

Comment: "But nothing of it doesn't works": this isn't helpful. You need to specify clearly what problems you're facing.

Comment: I need to parse json array('json') to my structure
`messages_in[i].readstate = Convert.ToBoolean(response["response"][i]["read_state"]);`, but I have error "Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue."

Comment: @jeffamaphone, seriously? He doesnt need to switch libraries just because he has a logic error

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  I miss-read this the first time.  It looked like he was rolling his own.  Now I see the JObject.Parse() call.  Nevermind.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(response["response"][0][i]["date"]);
```

response["response"][0] is an integer since the first element in response["response"] is "50961", so response["response"][0][i] is going to fail since you are trying to index something that isnt an array